# KeyError reading a nested JSON with Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-2.7, keyerror

I'm triying to acces to the value os a nested property insside a JSON file. The file is:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5b9058462f38434ab0d85cd3" }, "user_day_code" : "ead1db07fa526e19fe237115d5516fbdc5acb99057b885e8f662a147990b3c4b", "idplug_base" : 5, "track" : { "type" : "FeatureCollection", "features" : [ { "geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -3.7073786, 40.4237274997222 ] }, "type" : "Feature", "properties" : { "var" : "28015,ES,Madrid,Madrid,CALLE SAN BERNARDO 38,Madrid", "speed" : 1.75, "secondsfromstart" : 205 } }, { "geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -3.709896, 40.4191897997222 ] }, "type" : "Feature", "properties" : { "var" : "28013,ES,Madrid,Madrid,CUSTA SANTO DOMINGO 6,Madrid", "speed" : 4.63, "secondsfromstart" : 85 } } ] }, "user_type" : 1, "idunplug_base" : 17, "travel_time" : 263, "idunplug_station" : 40, "ageRange" : 0, "idplug_station" : 16, "unplug_hourTime" : { "$date" : "2018-09-01T01:00:00.000+0200" }, "zip_code" : "" }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5b9058462f38434ab0d85ce9" }, "user_day_code" : "420d9e220bd8816681162e15e9afcb1c69c5a756090728701083c5c0b23502f2", "idplug_base" : 12, "track" : { "type" : "FeatureCollection", "features" : [ { "geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -3.7022001, 40.4052982997222 ] }, "type" : "Feature", "properties" : { "var" : "28012,ES,Madrid,Madrid,GTA EMBAJADORES,Madrid", "speed" : 0.33, "secondsfromstart" : 351 } }, { "geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -3.698618, 40.4061700997222 ] }, "type" : "Feature", "properties" : { "var" : "28012,ES,Madrid,Madrid,RONDA ATOCHA 30,Madrid", "speed" : 6.36, "secondsfromstart" : 291 } }, { "geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -3.6949231, 40.4072785997222 ] }, "type" : "Feature", "properties" : { "var" : "28012,ES,Madrid,Madrid,RONDA ATOCHA,Madrid", "speed" : 4.77, "secondsfromstart" : 231 } }, { "geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -3.6920543, 40.4081501 ] }, "type" : "Feature", "properties" : { "var" : "28012,ES,Madrid,Madrid,PLAZA EMPERADOR CARLOS V 1,Madrid", "speed" : 4.38, "secondsfromstart" : 170 } } ] }, "user_type" : 1, "idunplug_base" : 26, "travel_time" : 382, "idunplug_station" : 85, "ageRange" : 2, "idplug_station" : 52, "unplug_hourTime" : { "$date" : "2018-09-01T01:00:00.000+0200" }, "zip_code" : "28009" }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5b9058462f38434ab0d85ced" }, "user_day_code" : "780f5c8157efe8e6dca44dbd689817d4b126364fca917f0e668bad9e7bf96939", "idplug_base" : 1, "track" : { "type" : "FeatureCollection", "features" : [ { "geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -3.69610249972222, 40.427829 ] }, "type" : "Feature", "properties" : { "var" : "28004,ES,Madrid,Madrid,PLAZA ALONSO MARTINEZ,Madrid", "speed" : 6.22, "secondsfromstart" : 200 } }, { "geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -3.69482799972222, 40.4282634997222 ] }, "type" : "Feature", "properties" : { "var" : "28010,ES,Madrid,Madrid,CALLE FERNANDO EL SANTO 4,Madrid", "speed" : 0, "secondsfromstart" : 140 } }, { "geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -3.69164359972222, 40.4280088 ] }, "type" : "Feature", "properties" : { "var" : "28010,ES,Madrid,Madrid,CALLE FERNANDO EL SANTO 20,Madrid", "speed" : 5.05, "secondsfromstart" : 80 } } ] }, "user_type" : 1, "idunplug_base" : 11, "travel_time" : 305, "idunplug_station" : 109, "ageRange" : 4, "idplug_station" : 58, "unplug_hourTime" : { "$date" : "2018-09-01T01:00:00.000+0200" }, "zip_code" : "28004" }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5b9058462f38434ab0d85cee" }, "user_day_code" : "a225ab7b4b74954cd9fbe8cc2ec63390cd04e92cdd1a2fe1e58d42faea082b21", "idplug_base" : 1, "track" : { "type" : "FeatureCollection", "features" : [ { "geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -3.72050759972222, 40.4277548 ] }, "type" : "Feature", "properties" : { "var" : "28008,ES,Madrid,Madrid,PASEO PINTOR ROSALES 49P,Madrid", "speed" : 0.86, "secondsfromstart" : 258 } }, { "geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -3.717881, 40.4274713 ] }, "type" : "Feature", "properties" : { "var" : "28008,ES,Madrid,Madrid,CALLE QUINTANA 17,Madrid", "speed" : 6.75, "secondsfromstart" : 199 } }, { "geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -3.7142441, 40.4297779997222 ] }, "type" : "Feature", "properties" : { "var" : "28015,ES,Madrid,Madrid,CALLE SERRANO JOVER 4D,Madrid", "speed" : 7.08, "secondsfromstart" : 139 } }, { "geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -3.71240559972222, 40.4341422997222 ] }, "type" : "Feature", "properties" : { "var" : "28015,ES,Madrid,Madrid,CALLE FERNANDO EL CATOLICO 47A,Madrid", "speed" : 5.25, "secondsfromstart" : 79 } }, { "geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -3.7089558, 40.4340593 ] }, "type" : "Feature", "properties" : { "var" : "28015,ES,Madrid,Madrid,CALLE FERNANDO EL CATOLICO 21,Madrid", "speed" : 5.61, "secondsfromstart" : 19 } } ] }, "user_type" : 1, "idunplug_base" : 1, "travel_time" : 262, "idunplug_station" : 168, "ageRange" : 4, "idplug_station" : 120, "unplug_hourTime" : { "$date" : "2018-09-01T01:00:00.000+0200" }, "zip_code" : "28015" }
```

The used code is:

```
d100 =  pd.read_json('test 1.json', lines=True)
d100["track"]["features"][0]["geometry"]["coordinates"]
```

A `KeyError` is retrieved although it appears that Key seems to be correct:

```
/home/cloudera/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
2558         try:
2559             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 2560
tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
2561         except KeyError as e1:
2562             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:


pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

KeyError: 'features'
```

Any help please on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `d100["track"]` is a *full column* of your `d100`, i. e. a *series:*

```
In[1]: d100["track"]                                                                
Out[1]:                                                                             
0    {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [{'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coord.....
1    {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [{'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coord.....
2    {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [{'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coord.....
3    {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [{'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coord.....
Name: track, dtype: object
```

It has **four** items (rows), but you *didn't specify any of them*.

So instead of

```
d100["track"]["features"][0]["geometry"]["coordinates"]
```

use (for individual items in the `d100["track"]` series)

```
d100["track"][0]["features"][0]["geometry"]["coordinates"] 
d100["track"][1]["features"][0]["geometry"]["coordinates"] 
d100["track"][2]["features"][0]["geometry"]["coordinates"] 
d100["track"][3]["features"][0]["geometry"]["coordinates"]
```

to obtain

> ```
> [-3.7073786, 40.4237274997222]
> [-3.7022000999999998, 40.4052982997222]
> [-3.69610249972222, 40.427829]
> [-3.72050759972222, 40.4277548]
> ```